# Why does printing a dataframe break python when constructed from numpy empty_like

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

consider numpy array `a`

```
a = np.array([None, None], dtype=object)
print(a)

[None None]
```

And `dfa`

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(dfa)

      0
0  None
1  None
```

Now consider numpy array `b`

```
b = np.empty_like(a)
print(b)

[None None]
```

It appears the same as `a`

```
(a == b).all()

True
```

## ***THIS! CRASHES MY PYTHON!!***  BE CAREFUL!!!

```
dfb = pd.DataFrame(b)  # Fine so far
print(dfb.values)

[[None]
 [None]]
```

However

```
print(dfb)  # BOOM!!!
```

Comment: Yes, tested on 2.7.12---Seg Fault..

Comment: Confirmed on Pandas 0.18.1 on Python 3.5.2.

Comment: In fact, it's not only printing: `dfa == dfb` also crashes.

Comment: You should [open an issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues) with the core developers to let them know this happens.

Comment: Do you guys think this is a pandas issue or numpy issue?

Comment: You can print the array without a problem so I'd say it is a pandas issue but I'm not sure.

Comment: @piRSquared Probably a `pandas` issue, since it's only a problem with the `panda`s constructor called on a valid `numpy` array. It doesn't hurt to cross-post on both Githubs, however.

Comment: Well, I tried `dfb.append(` and I couldn't finish typing, the kernel died.

Comment: Crashes for me too, but `dfb.values` works as expected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As reported [here,](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/14082) this is a bug, which is fixed in the master branch of `pandas` / the upcoming  `0.19.0` release.